# Calculate cumulative counts for `t` time periods without hardcoding

Tags: scala, dataframe

I want to calculated cumulative counts at different time steps. I have counts of events that happened during each time period `t`: now I want the cumulative number of events up to and including that period.

I can easily compute each cumulation separately, but it is tedious. I can append them back together with a `UnionAll`, but this would be tedious too, with a large number of time periods.

How could I do this more cleanly?

```
package main.scala

import java.io.File
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object Test {

    def main(args: Array[String]) {

        // Spark and SQL Context (gives access to Spark and Spark SQL libraries)
        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Merger")
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        val sqlContext = SQLContextSingleton.getInstance(sc)
        import sqlContext.implicits._

        // Count
        val count = Seq(("A",1,1),("A",1,2),("A",0,3),("A",0,4),("A",0,5),("A",1,6),
                        ("B",1,1),("B",0,2),("B",0,3),("B",1,4),("B",0,5),("B",1,6))
            .toDF("id","count","t")

        val count2 = count.filter('t <= 2).groupBy('id).agg(sum("count"), max("t"))

        val count3 = count.filter('t <= 3).groupBy('id).agg(sum("count"), max("t"))

        count.show()
        count2.show()
        count3.show()
    }
}
```

`count`:

```
+---+-----+---+
| id|count|  t|
+---+-----+---+
|  A|    1|  1|
|  A|    1|  2|
|  A|    0|  3|
|  A|    0|  4|
|  A|    0|  5|
|  A|    1|  6|
|  B|    1|  1|
|  B|    0|  2|
|  B|    0|  3|
|  B|    1|  4|
|  B|    0|  5|
|  B|    1|  6|
+---+-----+---+
```

`count2`:

```
+---+----------+------+
| id|sum(count)|max(t)|
+---+----------+------+
|  A|         2|     2|
|  B|         1|     2|
+---+----------+------+
```

`count3`:

```
+---+----------+------+
| id|sum(count)|max(t)|
+---+----------+------+
|  A|         2|     3|
|  B|         1|     3|
+---+----------+------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested it with Spark 1.5.2/Scala 10 and Spark 2.0.0/Scala 11 and it worked like a charm. It didn't work with Spark 1.6.2, I suspect it is because it is not compiled with Hive.

```
package main.scala

import java.io.File
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext


object Test {

    def main(args: Array[String]) {

        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test")
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        val sqlContext = SQLContextSingleton.getInstance(sc)
        import sqlContext.implicits._

        val data = Seq(("A",1,1,1),("A",3,1,3),("A",0,0,2),("A",4,0,4),("A",0,0,6),("A",2,1,5),
                         ("B",0,1,3),("B",0,0,4),("B",2,0,1),("B",2,1,2),("B",0,0,6),("B",1,1,5))
            .toDF("id","param1","param2","t")
        data.show()

        data.withColumn("cumulativeSum1", sum("param1").over( Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("t")))
            .withColumn("cumulativeSum2", sum("param2").over( Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("t")))
            .show()
    }
}
```

An improvement I am working on is to be able to apply it to several columns at once, instead of repeating `withColumn`. Inputs welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest de-normalizing your data in a way you can do cumulation in a one step.
This code also should scale well (since there is only one collection to driver).

Sorry for not using Dataframe API in my example (my spark installation is somewhat borked so I can't test Dataframes):

```
val count = sc.makeRDD(Seq(("A",1,1),("A",1,2),("A",0,3),("A",0,4),("A",0,5),("A",1,6),
  ("B",1,1),("B",0,2),("B",0,3),("B",1,4),("B",0,5),("B",1,6)))

// this is required only if number of timesteps is not known, this is the only operation that collects data to driver, and could even be broadcasted if large
val distinctTimesteps = count.map(_._3).distinct().sortBy(e => e, true).collect()

// this actually de-normalizes data so that it can be cumulated
val deNormalizedData = count.flatMap { case (id, c, t) =>
    // the trick is making composite key consisting of distinct timestep and your id: (distTimestep, id)
    distinctTimesteps.filter(distTimestep => distTimestep >= t).map(distTimestep => (distTimestep, id) -> c)
}

// just reduce by composite key and you are done
val cumulativeCounts = deNormalizedData.reduceByKey(_ + _)

// test
cumulativeCounts.collect().foreach(print)
```